# setBadgeText chrome extension losing counting numbers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

It is possible if method SetBadgeText don't lose counting numbers? What I am struggling is, when I click on a button and counter start to count numbers after that I'm going to check some other pages, sometimes counting starts from zero, the same thing is when I want to close chrome and open it again. How this is possible to save your actual setBadgeText number in memory and start from latest one without losing it?

> background.js

```
var counter = 0;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => {
    if(message === 'clicked') {
        counter += 1;
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
            text: counter.toString()
        });
    }
});
```

content-script.js

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(e.target.matches('[value="Google Search"]')) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage('clicked')
    }
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Counter",
    "version": "1.0",

    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://*/*"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "js": ["content-script.js"]
      }
    ],
    "description": "description",

    "background": {
      "persistent": false,
      "scripts": ["background.js"]

    },

    "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "counter"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the storage API: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage

The "sync" storage is synced to any Chrome browser you're logged into. The "local" storage is, uh, local.

Here's how you might integrate the storage API into your example:

```
// background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => {
    if(message === 'clicked') {
        chrome.storage.local.get('counter', ({counter}) => {
            counter += 1;
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
                text: counter.toString()
            });
            chrome.storage.local.set('counter', counter)
        })

    }
});
```

You will also need to add the "storage" permission to your manifest:

```
// manifest.json
{
    ...

    "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "counter"

    },

    permissions: [
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how this can be connected with setBadgetext? I only found functions where mostly HTML is used.

Comment: Added an example

Comment: Thanks this become more clear to me. Your reply was very helpful to me. Can you only tell me what function, variable should I use to load counter numbers when I close Chrome and want to turn it on again?

Comment: "what function, variable should I use to load counter numbers when I close Chrome and want to turn it on again?" The chrome storage API lets you save data and load it again later (after chrome has restarted). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry that I wrongly wrote to you. I wanted to say. If  chrome.storage.local.set('counter', counter) saves the latest numbers, what command should I use to load it again when I want to continue counting?

Comment: See my example. You'd use the `chrome.storage.local.get` function